# Wrong colors when using cv2.bitwise

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm having troubles when using cv2.bitwise, as seen at the end, I got pink image whereas I expect green colors.
But I can't understand why.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")[...,::-1]
shape = img.shape # 512,512,3

label = cv2.imread("mask.png", cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
shape = label.shape # 512,512

black_background = np.zeros(shape=shape, dtype=np.uint8)
shape = black_background.shape # 512,512

result = cv2.bitwise_not(img,black_background,mask=label)
cv2.imwrite("masked.png",result)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks for future help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are NOTing, or inverting, every bit of the `img` input, so the color is not as expected. You can solve this by NOTing the `img` input once before so that the second operation returns it to the expected color, like so:

```
img2 = img.copy()
cv2.bitwise_not(img, img2)
result = cv2.bitwise_not(img2, black_background, mask=label)
cv2.imwrite("masked.png",result)
```

**Edit**:
Alternatively, you can just add the `img` to a black image of matching shape, so that the colors are never messed with, like this:

```
black = np.zeros(shape=img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
result = cv2.add(img, black, black_background, mask=label)
cv2.imwrite("masked2.png", result)
```

Comment: Ok thanks ! Don't forget to add [...,::-1] to avoid loss of greenness
```result = cv2.bitwise_not(img2, black_background, mask=label)[...,::-1]```

Comment: @AngeloSantarossa No problem. For the second part, I'm not sure exactly what that accomplishes, other than flipping the color channels from BGR order to RGB order